# Flutter Material 3 change default Primary color

Tags: flutter, material3

I'm going to develop an app with a platter

When I tried to apply material 3, the primary color seemed to be fixed to light purple as the default.

Because of that, even the color of the dialog and bottom tab bar is light purple, so I want to change it to white, but I don't know what to do

I tried searching in stackoverflow, but I couldn't find the solution I wanted

Answer (score 1):

https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom

in this website, you can customize the m3 theme. When you export the theme, you will see 2 different dart file. One is for color_schemes.g.dart. (I recommend to change to name to color_schemes.dart). It is the scheme for the M3 design.

The other one is the what u should change in the main file to use the M3 design in your project. Then to use M3 color design:
After implementation,

If you want primary color Container =>

```
Container(
color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
)
```

if I understood correctly, you need to change the color white. So, there are two options:

- change one of the color property in schemes folder to use specific white color in your project (Also you should change the related property for darkColorScheme), then using it as color property
- or just use `color: Colors.white` if it is white in both lightTheme and darkTheme

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set these variables, and everything will be fine!

```
elevation: 0,
backgroundColor: Colors.white, --> your preferred color
```

example code

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      isDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      elevation: 0,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
        topRight: Radius.circular(20),
      )),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      builder: (context) {
        return Text("");
      })
```